# How can I write this code using nested for loop?

Tags: c

I have confused about this program... It is about printing current table that the range of voltage is from 0v to 30v and the range of resistance is from 100 to 1000 using [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) like the below picture.

I have written the code like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{

    int v, r, c;

    for (v = 0; v <= 50; v += 10) 
    {
        printf(":%d  ", v);
    }
    for (r = 0; r <= 1000; r += 100)
    {
        for()
    }
}
```

How can I write this code using only nested for loop?

Comment: You are absolutely right, sir. Actually I have thought like that the first line should be separated and the line of resistor and current would be use nested for loop..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a simple program that prints the table shown in your picture.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "    " );

    //this loop is only needed for printing the labels
    for ( int v = 0; v <= 50; v += 10 )
    {
        printf( "   :%-6d", v );
    }

    printf( "\n" );
    
    //this loop actually prints the calculations but
    //also prints the labels in the first column
    for ( int r = 100; r <= 1000; r += 100 )
    {
        printf( "%4d", r );
        for ( int v = 0; v <= 50; v += 10 )
        {
            printf( "   :%6.4lf", ((double)v) / r );
        }
        printf( "\n" );
    }

    return 0;
}
```